# How to find the difference of two dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on some Unit Testing Spark code which should be able to generate the difference between two dataframes(raw bucket and curated bucket). Both dataframes(buckets) are the same and we want to execute this code to capture the possible changes after we copy files from raw to curated. . I am aware that I can use `except` function as follow:

```
val difference =CuratedDataFrame.union(RawDataFrame).except(CuratedDataFrame.intersect(RawDataFrame))

+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
|record     |pid    |feetype      |freq     |default        |
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
|          1|     45|          FAC|        Y|              T| 
|          1|     45|          FAC|        Y|            TTY| 
|          1|     47|          FAC|        R|              M| 
|          1|     99|          FAC|        R|              M|
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
```

The except function is returning the entire row but my desired output is as follow :

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
|record     |pid    |feetype      |freq     |default        |
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
|       null|[47,99]|         null|     null|         null  |
|       null|   null|         null|     null|       [T, TTY]|
+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+-----
```

It means if there is a change in column then it should appear if there is no change then it should be hidden or Null.

For doing this I am using the following approach :

```
 val mapDiffs=(name: String) => when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name", null )
      .otherwise(array($"l.$name", $"r.$name")).as(name)
    val result = difference.as("l")
        .join(RawDataFrame.as("r"), $"l.primaryKey" === $"r.primaryKey","inner")
        .select($"l.primaryKey" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)
```

The above approach requires primary key to be able to join both dataframes and compare them row by row. None of the dataframes have primary key so I had to combine some of the columns to specify a primary key :

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------+
|record     |pid    |feetype      |freq     |default        |primaryKey|
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------+
|          1|     40|          FAC|        A|              N|    FAC40A|
|          1|     45|          FAC|        Y|              T|    FAC45Y|
|          1|     47|          FAC|        R|              M|    FAC47R|
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------+
```

The problem is that if any changes happen in the target bucket, the primary key will be consequently changed so comparing both dataframes would be impossible.

Comment: Are the DataFrames large - distributed in multiple partitions or they fit in single partition? Is the order of rows fixed in both dataframes or you might need to compare for 1 from raw to row 5 in curated or you always compare rowN to rowN?

Comment: I can't say that for sure because the size of DataFrames could be either large or small and there could be cases that they don't fit in a single partition. The order of rows is not fixed as well.

Comment: Is the coding completely correct? Can you post it integrally please?

Comment: Are all `records=1`?